# Flume "config" command stays in EXECING state when using hbase sink (Cloudera)

Tags: hbase, flume

I'm trying to use flume to stream logs into hbase.  I have a distributed flume setup running and an hbase cluster; both are using the same Zookeeper.  Flume is working with various commands (text, tail, custom sink filter) but when I try and use the following in flume shell or web UI:

```
exec config <node> 'tail("<sample file>")' '{ customDecorator => hbase("<table>","<row key>", "<col family>", "<col name>", "<col value>") }'
```

The command is in the EXECING state forever both on the command line and in the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have hbase-x.y.z.jar file in your flume lib or classpath.

also you will need hbase configuration on your flume installation such as copying hbase-site.xml to $flume_home/conf directory.

Ben